# How can I write a function in python to list in a single row all the items for every customer?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I need to feed this data to a Markov chain model.

This is how my data looks like (the format is a csv file):

[image]

And this is how I would like the output format of the parsing function (that I would ultimately end up putting in a text file):

X,Y,Z

A,B

C

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific technical questions, it is not the place to ask for others to do all your work for you. Please see: [ask], [help/on-topic], [tour].

Comment: @AMC I googled for quite awhile and I was not able to find anything specific that could help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reshape the dataframe and save the non-NaN values?

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bXFN.png)

Comment: Yes something like this is perfect